# Designer Worflows not resuming after the logic is making it to pause for 5 minutes

Tags: workflowservicefrontend

I have a 2013 environment and I am using  Designer 2010 workflow and the logic of the workflow is making it stop for 5 minutes and resume again after 5 minutes but this behavior is inconsistent as sometimes it resumes after the pause and sometimes it doesn't.

I came across this article not sure if anybody has tried this on 2013 and if it is the recommended steps

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2674684
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I remember back around 2010 there being some problems with the pause activities not resuming, but I also seem to recall a hotfix being implemented that resolved the issue.

Fast forward to today, I'm confident that those issues would be ironed out; what I would suggest is creating a really simple test workflow that does nothing but pause for 5 minutes, then write a message to the history. Let it run for a while, and if that appears to work properly, there might be something else wrong with your specific workflow.

Comment: I tried what you have told me and looks like its intermittent and sometimes it gets stuck for 40 minutes and then resume not sure what's happening(see the attached image) Do you think I should try this $webapp = Get-SPWebApplication -identity http://<web app name>
• $webapp.UpdateWorkflowConfigurationSetttings()

Comment: Are you seeing the same errors in the Uls logs?